# HTML - hyperlink href is not rendered by the browser

Tags: html, hyperlink

I have several HTML documents in one folder locally. The pages link to eachother through hyperlinks. When I open a page in a browser the hyperlinks do not work and aren't even displayed in the developer tools. What is wrong?

JS

```
$('.only_css').removeAttr("href");  // I found this after putting the question sorry
```

HTML

```
       <div class="label_css">
            <a href="contact.html"  class="only_css" target="_self">
                <h3>Contact</h3>
            </a>
        </div>
```

Folder

```
contact.html
guestbook.html
index.html
```

Comment: You are missing a closing `"` after the `href-"contact.html`

Comment: sorry, it was a spelling mistake here, but it still does not work

Comment: What browser are you using?

Comment: can you post the URL of a page where this is happening?

Comment: share more of your code... the issue must be something else on the page (unclosed parent element or sibling maybe)

Comment: @JRulle I pasted the whole code now

Comment: As you can see here: [**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/jrulle/2Zx26/), it works fine, so show more code from the page... also, try removing your class and target attributes - if it works with them removed you will have narrowed down the root of your issue.

Comment: @JRulle you are right there was JS running in the background:  $('.only_css').removeAttr("href");

Comment: So why did you mark @DanielPanic's answer as correct when it isn't?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<a href="contact.html"> Contact </a>
```

Assuming that's literally the code you have. It is missing a `"`.

Comment: sorry, it was a spelling mistake here in stackoverflow, but it still does not work

Comment: Hummm so provide more code. Like and jsfiddle or something.

Answer (score 1):

Try to render on different browser

Answer (score 0):

Something else in your code must be causing this behavior.
Check for unclosed parent/sibling elements, rogue Javascript, missing DOCTYPE, etc.